# Get the internal id for a refineablestring

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I'm building up a query which will redirect the user to the search page with the relevant query info. My problem is the only way I know how to get the internal id for the refinablestring is via the address bar, I need a way to be able to get the internal id via JavaScript.

When I say internal ID I mean:

Name: Refinablestring00

Internal id: ǂǂ446f63756d656e7460547970652031

Query that gets generated (decoded):

```
/sites/example/pages/Search.aspx#Default={"k":"*","r": 
[{"n":"RefinableString00","t": 
["\"ǂǂ4469736363706c696e652032\""],"o":"and","k":false,"m":null}]}
```

To clarify, I want to be able to get the internal id and I have access to JSOM/client side. What options do I have?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not *officially* documented, but here we go. 
Let's take a look how refiner filter is represented:

```
{ 
     "k": queryText,    //search query 
     "r": [   //<- the list of refiners
              { 
                  "n": propertyName,   //property value 
                  "t": [token],  //encoded property value (see below for a more details)  
                  "o": "and",    //(or,and) operators
                  "k": false, 
                  "m": null 
              }
      ],
      //another refiners go here.. 
      "l": lcid   //language 
}
```

where `token` represents the **encoded** property value which could be generated like this:

```js
var strToHex = function (value) {
     var hex = unescape(encodeURIComponent(value))
        .split('').map(function(v){
             return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
        }).join('')
     return hex; 
};


//Usage
var propertyValue = "Jon Doe";
var token = "\"ǂǂ" + strToHex(propertyValue) + "\"";
console.log(token);
```

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to generate search url which includes filter for refiner with property name `DisplayAuthor` and value `Jon Doe`

```js
function createRefiner(queryText,propertyName, propertyValue,lcid) {
     lcid = lcid || 1033;
     var strToHex = function (value) {
                var hex = unescape(encodeURIComponent(value))
                    .split('').map(function(v){
                         return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
                   }).join('')
                return hex; 
     };
     var token = "\"ǂǂ" + strToHex(propertyValue) + "\"";
     return { 
              "k": queryText, 
              "r": [{ "n": propertyName, "t": [token], "o": "and", "k": false, "m": null }], 
              "l": lcid 
     };
}


//Usage
var refiner = createRefiner("*","DisplayAuthor","Jon Doe");
var queryGroupName = "Default";
var refinerFilter = queryGroupName + '=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(refiner));
var pageUrl = "/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx" + '#' + refinerFilter;
console.log(pageUrl);
```

Comment: Hey dude, bit of a late reply but very nice answer! I tested this yesterday and it works as expected - thank you.